# How to set seek bar thumb position in the following link

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hi i have tried to set position of custom seekbar with seekBar.setprogress(value) following [this](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) tutorial . I spent lot of time in search of solution but couldn't find it .
for example min is 10 and max is 90 and i want to set thumb position in between 30-60 by default .
Please help me out .

```
RangeSeekBar<Long> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Long>(minDate1.getTime(), maxDate1.getTime(), _context);
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.viewgroup);
            seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Long>() {

                public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(
                        RangeSeekBar<?> bar,
                        Long minValue, Long maxValue) {
                    Fragment fragment = new MenuActivity();
                    tv1.setText(getDate(min, "hh:mm a"));
                    tv2.setText(getDate(max, "hh:mm a"));
                }
            });

            layout.addView(seekBar);
```

RangeSeekBar class reference from [THIS LINK](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: we have to set thumb positions in the given code by some int or long value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Using

```
RangeSeekBar<Long> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Long>(minDate1.getTime(), maxDate1.getTime(), _context);
seekBar.setSelectedMinValue(30);
seekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(60);
```